# Capybara like text search in Javascript

Tags: javascript, software-testing

I'm testing a Ember.js (1.13.1) app with Mocha (and Chai). I want to write expections on the page content without specifying selectors like I do in my capybara feature specs:

```
expect(page).to have_content 'Account created'
```

I can use `jQuery('body').text()` to extract the `innerText` but it needs farther parsing to remove whitespace and line-breaks.

A additional bonus would be if it could find elements such as buttons by content.